# Does java have a variable constant defined for / like it does for \ (File.separator)?

Tags: java

I want to use `/` in my Java program.

But I'm searching for a variable constant -- something like `File.separator` (which gives `\`).

Comment: Use [`Paths`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) and [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) classes to manipulate file paths.

Comment: `File.separator` will return `/` on e.g. Linux systems. But you don't really need it. Java will happily work with `/` even on Windows

Answer (score 5):

Java has [`java.io.File.separator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#separator) and [`java.io.File.separatorChar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#separatorChar), which will give the standard path separator for the current operating system. For example on Linux that will return `/`, and on Windows `\`. If you want a constant for `/` irrespective of the underlying OS, you will need to define it yourself in your own code.

You can also get the path separator using [`java.nio.file.FileSystem.getSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getSeparator()), for example using `FileSystems.getDefault().getSeparator()`.

However, it is better to leave path construction to [`java.nio.file.Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html) instead of concatenating sub-paths yourself.

If I'm not mistaken, if an OS has different separators for different file systems (which AFAIK is only a theoretical concern), then `Path` should be able to take care of that for you.

As a simplification, on the common operating systems (Linux, MacOS and Windows), you can always use `/` as the path separator in your Java code.

Comment: I think saadhya simply assumes that `File.seprator` always returns `\ ` and doesn't realize that it's platform dependent

Comment: actually I'm trying to build a URL in a method but where I want to use only '/' that is the reason I want a forward slash. Could you help me with that?

Comment: @saadhyaT In that case, use a URI builder, for example Spring's UriComponentsBuilder.